# Image compressing Android

Tags: java, image, image-compression

I have created this app based on tutorials, ATM it successfully open the camera and displays it as imgOriginal on the screen. When i press the compress button I get a error relating to '.compressToFile(imageBitmap);

Error Message:
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.photocompressor, PID: 11123
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.io.File.getName()' on a null object reference
at id.zelory.compressor.Compressor.compressToFile(Compressor.java:56)
at com.example.photocompressor.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:149)

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    // if (resultCode == RESULT_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK ) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && resultCode != RESULT_IMAGE) {


        btnCompress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        final Uri imageUri = data.getData();

        try {
            final InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
            final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
            imgOriginal.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
            ////originalImage = new File(imageUri.getEncodedPath().replace("raw/", ""));
            long size = DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(this, imageUri).length();
            //txtOriginal.setText("Size: " + Formatter.formatShortFileSize(this, originalImage.length()));
            txtOriginal.setText("Size: " + Formatter.formatShortFileSize(this, size));
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Size: " + size, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Size: " + Formatter.formatShortFileSize(this, originalImage.length()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something went Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No Image Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // }
```

Below is the compress button, error appears in '.compressToFile'. I would ideally like to have the option to replace the original file or to save as a new file, but havent even got the replace file to work yet.

```
 btnCompress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int quality = seekBar.getProgress();
            int width = Integer.parseInt(txtWidth.getText().toString());
            int height = Integer.parseInt(txtHeight.getText().toString());
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Quality " + quality, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            try {
                compressedImage = new Compressor(MainActivity.this)
                        .setMaxWidth(width)
                        .setMaxHeight(height)
                        .setQuality(quality)
                        .setCompressFormat(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG)
                        .setDestinationDirectoryPath(filepath)
                        //.compressToFile(originalImage);
                        .compressToFile(imageBitmap);

                File finalFile = new File(filepath, originalImage.getName());
                Bitmap finalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(finalFile.getAbsolutePath());
                imgCompressed.setImageBitmap(finalBitmap);

                //long newsize = DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(this, image);
                //txtCompressed.setText("size: " + Formatter.formatShortFileSize(MainActivity.this,newsize));

                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, filepath + " Something went Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error while Compressing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }


        }
    });
```

Comment: And what is the error message? Always include relevant information, such as complete error message and stack trace, *in the question*.

Comment: Error Message: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.photocompressor, PID: 11123 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.io.File.getName()' on a null object reference at id.zelory.compressor.Compressor.compressToFile(Compressor.java:56) at com.example.photocompressor.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:149)